How do I pass a value to a svelte.ts file?
I am currently creating an Svelte 5 app using Konva.
This is what the component looks like:
<!-- Canvas.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
    import { Stage, Rect, Layer, Line } from 'svelte-konva';
    import { generateGrid, getPadding } from '$drawingTools/grid.svelte';
    import { createRect, handleDragend } from '$drawingTools/rectangle.svelte';
    import { zoom, dragNav } from '$drawingTools/navigation.svelte';
    import { rectangle } from '$drawingTools/shapes/classes.svelte';
    import { handleKeyDown } from '$drawingTools/undoRedo.svelte';
    
    let height: number = $state(window.innerHeight);
    let width: number = $state(window.innerWidth);
    let rects: rectangle[] = $state([]);
    let grid: any = $state();
    let padding: number = $derived(getPadding());
    let undoRedoMemory: rectangle[] = $state([]);
    
    $effect(() => {
        grid = [];
        grid = generateGrid(width, height, padding);
    });
</script>

<Stage
    {height}
    {width}
    draggable={true}
    onclick={(e) => rects.push(createRect(e))}
    onwheel={zoom}
    ondragmove={(e) => {
        dragNav(e, width, height, padding);
    }}
>
    <Layer>
        {#each grid as line}
            <Line {...line} />
        {/each}
        {#each rects as rect, index}
            <Rect
                {...rect}
                draggable={true}
                ondragend={(e: any) => handleDragend(e, rect, index, rects)}
            />
        {/each}
    </Layer>
</Stage>

<svelte:window onkeydown={handleKeyDown} />

In order to keep my code clean, I want to keep the functions inside of .svelte.ts files, like this one for example:
// undoRedo.svelte.ts

// something like import { rects, undoRedoMemory } from 'Canvas.svelte'

export function handleKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    if ((e.ctrlKey && e.key === 'z') || e.key === 'Z') {
        deleteLatest();
    }

    if ((e.ctrlKey && e.key === 'y') || e.key === 'Y') {
        readdLatest();
    }
}

function deleteLatest() {
    let latest = rects.length - 1;
    if (latest >= 0) {
        undoRedoMemory.push(rects[latest]);
        rects.pop();
    }
}

function readdLatest() {
    let latest = undoRedoMemory.length - 1;
    if (latest >= 0) {
        rects.push(undoRedoMemory[latest]);
        undoRedoMemory.pop();
    }
}

In this case, I'd like to export the undoRedoMemory to the undoRedo.svelte.ts file in order for the functions to work with the array without having to pass it to each current and yet to come functions manually.
Apparently I am supposed to use the $props() rune, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.
Also I am rather new to application development and this is my first bigger project, so if I am missing any fundamental point here, please enlighten me.

When handling keys, you should also check for negative state on all the other modifier keys, otherwise you overfire on things that may not be intended for your handler.

$props() is for component properties, i.e. passing values between component instances (see tutorial). Only export let syntax within components should be changed, it has nothing to do with regular JS/TS modules.
You cannot import values directly from the component because there could be any number of instances. Instead, you could wrap your function in a class or factory function that takes the necessary data as arguments.
E.g. something along the lines of:
export function keyDownHandler(
  rects: rectangle[],
  undoRedoMemory: rectangle[],
) {
    function handleKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent) {
        // ...
    }
    
    function deleteLatest() {
        // ...
    }
    
    function readdLatest() {
        // ...
    }

    return handleKeyDown;
}

<svelte:window onkeydown={keyDownHandler(rects, undoRedoMemory)} />

Note that the function is called as part of the template (HTML part of the component), so it will re-execute if rects or undoRedoMemory are reassigned. If you were to extract the function to the script part, this would not be the case unless you also use an $effect.
(In your current code this should not matter because there are no re-assignments and changes via push/pop etc. are captured by a Proxy object around the arrays that is created by $state.)
